# Why does it appear that PHP core functions have empty blocks?

Tags: php

I'm digging through PHP (using PHPStorm) to figure out how Exceptions work, and I keep running across an interesting situation where functions have empty blocks.

For example, in `PHP Runtime/Core/Core.php`, the `error_reporting` function is defined like this:

```
function error_reporting ($level = null) {}
```

And it's not unique. The top of that files goes like this (ignore all the documentation comments):

```
<?php

// Start of Core v.5.3.6-13ubuntu3.2

function zend_version () {}

function func_num_args () {}

function func_get_arg ($arg_num) {}

function func_get_args () {}

function strlen ($string) {}
```

Why are the braces all empty? Looking through other core files, I see a lot of function definitions, but no actual code. Where is everything?

Comment: Those look like stub definitions, not actual implementations.

Comment: I *think* it's within the PHP processor itself.

Comment: These are only there provided so your IDE can provide you with auto-completion and similar useful functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Core" files you're looking at are supplied with PHPStorm to support autocompletion. They aren't actually used by the PHP interpreter. These functions are actually all implemented within the PHP interpreter, in native C code.

The real definition of `error_reporting`, for instance, is in [`Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/bc5811f361ead53a803046b128a64d15aba2f2e5/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L670). It's unlikely to tell you much unless you're quite familiar with PHP internals, though.

Comment: I think Giedrius nailed it in the comments. If you want to edit your answer to incorporate that, I'll mark you accepted.

Comment: @amflare I'm a little hesitant to jump to that conclusion without knowing exactly what you were looking at. What IDE are you using, and what path did it show for that file?

Comment: PHPStorm and the path was `PHP Runtime/Core/Core.php`

Comment: @amflare Aha. Updated accordingly.

Comment: By the way, you can find the corresponding PhpStorm stubs here: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/blob/master/Core/Core.php.

Comment: @localheinz - Yep, that's what I was seeing.